# Как настроить изменение размера виджета в соответствии с размером главного окна?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, qt-designer, qsplitter

Решил учиться писать собственные приложения и столкнулся с непониманием *Qt Designer*.

**Полная задача:**

Тут подробнее изложена идея.
Уже советовался по реализации: [Как создать персональный виджет в главном окне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1322701/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b5)

**Коротко:**

Хочу написать простенькую прогу, в одно окно. В нем 3 отдельных под-окна (см. скриншот, предположительно что-то показываю). Мне советовали использовать QSplitter. Это решило тот вопрос, но возникли следующие проблемы.

**ВОПРОС:**

1. Как реализовать изменения размеров виджетов с изменением размеров главного окна?
2. Можно ли это сделать в Qt Designer?

Я видел подобные вопросы, но там создавались окна с фиксированными шаблонами (кнопки, текст, окно и тд.). В то же время у меня живые окна с возможностью вручную менять габариты. Тем более, если выбрать *LayOut* для *Центрального виджета*, я не смогу создать *splitter*  для 3 окон (в моем случае QFrame, ведь в будущем собираюсь добавлять туда функционал )

3. Можно ли в том же Qt Designer добавить условия увеличения?

Хотелось бы, чтоб темно-серое и светло-зеленое окна увеличивались с главным окном, не меняя соотношения сторон 1х1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE**

Ui файл. ПанельМеню я хотел делать вручную, так что это стоит учесть.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>GcsWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="GcsWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1000</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>GcsWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>1000</width>
     <height>600</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="sizeIncrement">
    <size>
     <width>1</width>
     <height>1</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="baseSize">
    <size>
     <width>1000</width>
     <height>600</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="BUT_Menu">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>80</width>
      <height>30</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="sizePolicy">
     <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
      <horstretch>0</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
     </sizepolicy>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background-color: rgb(235,235,235);
    border-radius: 1px;
    Text-align:center;

}
QPushButton:hover{
    background-color:rgb(225, 225, 225);
}
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
    border-style: inset;
}
QPushButton:open{
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
    border-style: inset;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>MENU</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>31</y>
      <width>1000</width>
      <height>569</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="orientation">
     <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="handleWidth">
     <number>1</number>
    </property>
    <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter">
     <property name="baseSize">
      <size>
       <width>0</width>
       <height>0</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="handleWidth">
      <number>1</number>
     </property>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
      <property name="baseSize">
       <size>
        <width>300</width>
        <height>300</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
      <property name="baseSize">
       <size>
        <width>300</width>
        <height>269</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(213, 255, 216);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_3">
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(248, 194, 255);</string>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: покажите, пожалуйста, ваш `.ui`

Comment: @S.Nick , добавил файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете просто создать разделитель, содержащий элементы, в *Qt Designer*:

1. Сначала разместите свои виджеты в дизайнере (их не должно быть в макете).
2. Выберите виджеты, которые вы хотите включить в разделитель
   (удерживая *CTL* и нажимая на них)
3. Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши выбранный виджет и в меню Layout и
   выберите `Lay Out Horizontally in Splitter` или `Lay Out Vertically in Splitter`.
4. Теперь примените `layout` сетки к выбранным виджетам.

**q1322996.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>480</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout" stretch="0">
    <item>
     <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter_2">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="lineWidth">
        <number>2</number>
       </property>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout" stretch="0">
        <property name="leftMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="topMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="rightMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="bottomMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <item>
         <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
          <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>150</width>
             <height>150</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(85, 255, 127);</string>
           </property>
           <property name="frameShape">
            <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="frameShadow">
            <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
           </property>
          </widget>
          <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_3">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>150</width>
             <height>150</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(85, 255, 255);</string>
           </property>
           <property name="frameShape">
            <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="frameShadow">
            <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_4">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>300</width>
         <height>300</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 170, 255);</string>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>640</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Стало понятнее.

Comment: @Anton-Vas пожалуйста